# return static structure array pointer with get()

Tags: c, pointers, struct, return-value

I have a file in my project that has a local structure array defined like `MyStruct_t myStruct[SIZE]` which I can use well within that module.  Now I would like to make it accessible to a different code module, so I came up with a function:

```
MyStruct_t *GetStruct(void) {
  return myStruct;
}
```

But when I call this from my different module, I get an error `expression must be a modifiable lvalue`. My caller looks like:

```
void myFunc(void) {
    MyStruct_t locStruct;
    locStruct = GetStruct();
}
```

How can I do this best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can do the following way

```
void myFunc( void ) 
{
   MyStruct_t locStruct[SIZE];
   MyStruct_t *p = GetStruct();
   memcpy( locStruct, p, SIZE * sizeof( MyStruct_t ) );
}
```

Or it might be enough to have a pointer to the first element of the array

```
void myFunc( void ) 
{
   MyStruct_t *locStruct = GetStruct();
}
```

In this case the syntax for accessing elements of the array will be the same as for example `locStruct[i]`

Comment: I don't think he wants a copy of the array!

Answer (score 2):

`GetStruct` returns a pointer to `myStruct[SIZE]` element, not a `MyStruct_t`. Unless you really need a copy, make `locStruct` a pointer, like this:

```
MyStruct_t *locStruct = GetStruct();
```

note that `locStruct` is an *array* of `MyStruct_t`, of size `SIZE`.

If you do want to make a copy, dereference `GetStruct()`'s result:

```
MyStruct_t locStruct = *GetStruct();
```

This would produce a copy of the initial element of `myStruct` array.

Since `GetStruct` does not provide additional services except accessing `myStruct`, you might as well make `myStruct` global (`extern`) instead of `static`.

Finally, you could change `GetStruct` to access a specific element. This would also take care of detecting overruns - i.e. attempts at getting an element past the `SIZE` or at a negative index:

```
bool GetStruct(int index, MyStruct_t *ptr) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= SIZE) {
        return false;
    }
    *ptr = myStruct[index];
    return true;
}
```

Now the call of `GetStruct()` would look like this:

```
MyStruct_t locStruct;
if (GetStruct(5, &locStruct)) {
    // All good
} else {
    // Error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetStruct` returns a pointer, so your `locStruct` variable should be a pointer, too.

```
void myFunc(void) {
    MyStruct_t *locStruct;
    locStruct = GetStruct();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `myStruct` is global in the other module, then you might be looking for the `extern` keyword. Just put this in the other module:

```
extern MyStruct_t myStruct[];
```

(I've assumed MyStruct_t is a `typedef`ed name. Otherwise you'd need to put the keyword `struct` before it, of course.)

This also requires access to the declaration of `MyStruct`. Put that in a header file and include it in both modules.

Here's a simple example:

```
// main.h ------------------------------------------------

typedef struct {
  int a, b, c;
} AStruct;

// func.h ------------------------------------------------

void func(void);

// main.c ------------------------------------------------

#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "func.h"

AStruct as[100];

int main(void) {
    func();
    printf("%d,%d,%d\n", as[0].a, as[0].b, as[0].c);
    return 0;
}

// func.c ------------------------------------------------

#include "main.h"
#include "func.h"

extern AStruct as[];

void func(void) {
    as[0].a = 1;
    as[0].b = 2;
    as[0].c = 3;
}
```